# The analyzer produces case_block_not_terminated in a case block with nested if/else statement, although return statement is executable

Tags: dart

I have a case that I would like to understand.

If I have following Switch Case statement with nested if/else:

```
f(int x, int y) {
  switch (x) {
    case 0:
      if (y > 10) { 
        return 'StringA';
      } else {
        return 'StringB';
      }
    default:
      return 'Anything';
  }
}
```

the analyses throws an error: `case_block_not_terminated`

> case_block_not_terminated: The last statement of the ‘case’ should be
> ‘break’, ‘continue’, ‘rethrow’, ‘return’, or ‘throw’.

if I add a `break;` at the end of the case statement the error disappears, but it is clearly dead code, because one of the return statements should be executed.

```
f(int x, int y) {
  switch (x) {
    case 0:
      if (y > 10) { 
        return 'StringA';
      } else {
        return 'StringB';
      }
      break;
    default:
      return 'Anything';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue should go away when you enable the null-safety feature.  The analyzer's code flow analysis has been much improved for NNBD to fix this [and similar cases](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/1139). (You can verify this in [DartPad with null-safety enabled](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?null_safety=true).)

In the meantime, you also could just remove the superfluous `else`:

```dart
String f(int x, int y) {
  switch (x) {
    case 0:
      if (y > 10) { 
        return 'StringA';
      }
      return 'StringB';
    default:
      return 'Anything';
  }
}
```

or remove the superfluous `default` case:

```dart
String f(int x, int y) {
  switch (x) {
    case 0:
      if (y > 10) { 
        return 'StringA';
      } else {
        return 'StringB';
      }
  }
  return 'Anything';
}
```